# Navigate to MainPage from Frame

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

Current Position:
  MainPage -> 
    MainPageFrame ->
      FramePageFrame ->

Trying to use the following code from within the FramePageFrame:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var page = (MainPage)Window.Current.Content;             
       page.MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
```

MainPage:

```
    public Frame MainFrame
    {
        get { return this.frameContent; }
    }
```

The code takes me back to the main page, but then it also seems to load MainPage *again* inside of the frameContent.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing

```
page.MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

to

```
page.MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(Command)); 
// Command is another page I want to load after returning to MainPage
```

Calling `Navigate` on a Frame control not only takes a user to that page, but also navigates the frame (apparently).